# Перестали работать плитки API

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Использую API Карт. Для получения плиток геодемоном производится серия вот таких запросов:
curl 'http://vec04.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=map&v=18.04.12&x=23&y=12&z=5&g=G'

В итоге возвращается ошибка **"Matched by flapping URL mask for vec00.maps.yandex.net"**
Что она означает?

Comment: Такое, наверно, лучше у самого яндекса спрашивать...

Answer (score 1):

Запросы вида **vec0х.maps.yandex.net** являются обращениями к внутренним ресурсам Яндекса. Эти сервисы не являются частью API — их использование запрещено [пользовательским соглашением](https://yandex.ru/legal/maps_api/) и работоспособность не гарантируется.
Для показа карты следует использовать возможности [JavaScript API](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/).

Также, в линейке API Карт был анонсирован [Tiles API](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/tiles/) для загрузки подложки карты через http-запросы. Tiles API предоставляется только на коммерческой основе и сейчас находится в закрытой бете.